# How to use this json in handlebars js

Tags: json, handlebars.js

Here is the full code.

HTML part:

```
<script id="company_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">                            
{{#each CDataMap}}
<div>{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
<p></p> 
</script>
```

JS part

```
var source   = $("#company_template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data= {
"CDataMap" : {
"name": "Jim Cowart",
"location": {
"city": {
    "name": "Chattanooga",
    "population": 167674
},
"state": {
    "name": "Tennessee",
    "abbreviation": "TN",
    "population": 6403000
}
},
"company": "appendTo"
}
};

$("p").append(template(data));
```

I want to use this using handlebars js.

When am using it am getting object object display only.

I need the correct code.

Comment: are you using alert or console.log to see object object?

Comment: When i pass this json in handlebars js am getting object object display..am not using alert or console.

Comment: I edited the question with full code

Answer (score 0):

Handlebar each expects iterative elements. Data which you are supplying needs to be modified.
 Below code works

```
<script id="company_template" type="text/x-handlebarstemplate">                            

{{#each CDataMap}}

<div>Name : {{this.name}} <br/>

    Location: {{this.location.city.name}} <br />
    Population: {{this.location.city.population}}
</div>
{{/each}}

</script>
<p></p>
```

JS side

```
var data= {
"CDataMap" : [
    {
        "name": "Jim Cowart",  
        "location": {
            "city": {
                "name": "New york",
                "population": 494949494
                }
        }
    },

  ]
};

var templateSource   = $("#company_template").html();
template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);
studentHTML = template(data);
$("p").append(studentHTML);
```

Comment: Can you showing me the working code in jsfiddle becoz when I used your code it doesn't shows any result

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your example is that CDataMap is not an array of objects, so you cannot iterate through them.
 This is a valid example:

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(function () {
            var source = $("#company_template").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

            var data = {
                "CDataMap": [{
                    "name": "Jim Cowart",
                    "location": {
                        "city": {
                            "name": "Chattanooga",
                            "population": 167674
                        },
                        "state": {
                            "name": "Tennessee",
                            "abbreviation": "TN",
                            "population": 6403000
                        }
                    },
                    "company": "appendTo"
                }]
            };

            $("p").append(template(data));
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

And also the p tag or any element you'll use to put the result in must be outside of the template, like this:

```
<script id="company_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each CDataMap}}
        <div>{{this.name}}</div>
        <div>{{this.location.city.name}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<p></p>
```